# In R, how do I use stub to create names (of data frames, variables & plots) in a loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm working with a set of results of `INLA` package in R. These results are stored in objects with meaningful names so I can have, for instance, `model_a`, `model_b`... in current environment. For each of these models I'd like to do several processing tasks including extracting of the data to separate data frame, which can then be used to merge to spatial data to create map, etc.

Turning to simpler, reproducible example let's assume two results

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2, 10, 20, labels = c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
model_a <- lm(weight ~ group)
model_b <- lm(weight ~ group - 1)
```

I can handle the steps for an individual model, for instance:

```
model_a_sum <- data.frame(var = character(1), model_a_value = numeric(1))
model_a_sum$var <- "Intercept"
model_a_sum$model_a_value <- model_a$coefficients[1]

png("model_a_plot.png")
plot(model_a, las = 1)
dev.off()
```

Now, I'd like to reuse this code for each of the models, essentially constructing correct names depending on the model I'm using. I'm more Stata than R person and inside Stata that would be a trivial task to use the stub of a name (`model_a`, or even `a` only..) and construct `foreach` loop that would implement all the steps, adapting names for each of the models.

In R, for loops have been bashed all over the internet so I presume I shouldn't attempt to venture into the territory of:

```
models <- c("model_a", "model_b", "model_c")

for (model in models) {

  ...

}
```

What would be the better solution for such scenario?

---

**Update 1**: Since comments suggested that `for` might indeed be an option I'm trying to put all the tasks into a loop. So far I manged to name the data frame correctly using `assign` and get correct data plotted under correct name using `get`:

```
models <- c("model_a", "model_b")

for (i in 1:length(models)) {

  # create df
  name.df <- paste0(models[i], "_sum")
  assign(name.df, data.frame(var = character(1), value = numeric(1)))

  # replace variables of df with results from the model

  # plot and save
  name.plot <- paste0(models[i], "_plot.png")
  png(name.plot)
  plot(get(models[i]), which = 1, las = 1)
  dev.off()  

}
```

Is this reasonable approach? Any better solutions?

One thing I cannot solve is having the second variable of the df named according to the model (ie. `model_a_value` instead of current `value`. Any ideas how to solve that?

Comment: I think the `for` solution is a fine choice in this situation, where your function is going to be producing files to write to disk like you're doing. Make a function of your process with object name as the variable, then `for (i in 1:length(models)) your.function(models[i])`.

Comment: I think a for loop is completely appropriate for this kind of task, though you may benefit from parallelization if you have a ton of these model objects to process - in which case, I'd make use of the `foreach` package.

Comment: "In R, for loops have been bashed all over the internet " Everything last forever on internet, for loops in R __were__ slow, that's not the case anymore so there's no reason to avoid them when they're of choice. Avoid them if you can work on a "vectorized" (i.e using only functions with can take a vector as entry) way as the processing is optimized for this.

Comment: Another option would be to make a list of your model formulae; then make separate functions a) to estimate the model and extract the coefficients and b) to estimate and then plot the model; then use `lapply()` and `rapply()`, respectively, to apply those functions to the list of model formulae.

Comment: @hoffmanc @Tensibai @ulfelder Thanks all for the comments. Will try to pursue `for` solution.

Answer (score 4):

Some general tips/advice:

1. As mentioned in comments, don't believe much of the negativity about `for` loops in R. The issue is not that they are bad, but more that they are correlated with some bad code patterns that are inefficient.
2. More important is to use the right data organization. **Don't keep the models each in a separate object!**. Put them in a list:

   ```
   l <- vector("list",3)
   l[[1]] <- lm(...)
   l[[2]] <- lm(...)
   l[[3]] <- lm(...)
   ```
3. Then name the list:

   ```
   names(l) <- paste0("model_",letters[1:3])
   ```

Now you can loop over the list without resorting to awkward and unnecessary tools like `assign` and `get`, and more importantly when you're ready to step up from `for` loops to tools like `lapply` you're all good to go.

I would use similar strategies for your data frames as well.

Comment: Even if I answered on the original question as sometimes you don't have choice on what you get as input I fully agree with this post.

Comment: Thanks @joran. Will try to adapt the code to use the list of all models. One question though: does that solution implies that I have to specify the number of modes that will be used here? In your case - 3?

Comment: @radek Yes. Technically it is possible to simply assign to the end of the list and grow it, but that will scale poorly since it forces lots of copying. It is fine to create a list that overestimates the final length and then remove the entries you don't need.

Comment: I don't the get the "move from for loop to lapply" interest, `for (m in models) {` or `lapply(models,function(x) { ` would be equivalent functionally, lapply would even be a little slower. What am I forgetting there ? (as I'm quite sure I do forget something :))

Answer (score 3):

See @joran answer, this one is to show use of `assign` and `get` but should be avoided when possible.

I would go this way for the for loop:

```
for (model in models) {
  m <- get(model) # to get the real model object
  # create the model_?_sum dataframe
  assign(paste0(model,"_sum"), data.frame(var = "Intercept", value = m$coefficients[1]))
  assign(paste0(model,"_sum"), setNames( get(paste0(model,"_sum")), c("var",paste0(model,"_value"))) ) # per comment to rename the value column thanks to @Franck in chat for the guidance

  # paste0 to create the text
  png(paste0(model,"_plot.png"))
  plot(m, las = 1) # use the m object to graph
  dev.off()
}
```

which give the two images and this:

```
> model_a_sum
                var value
(Intercept) Integer 5.032
> model_b_sum
             var value
groupCtl Integer 5.032
>
```

I'm unsure of why you wish this dataframe, but I hope this give clues on how to makes variables names and how to access them.

Comment: Thanks. One question: Is it possible to have the `value` replaced dynamically to reflect the model it comes from? For instance naming it `model_a_value`. As for reason of having this data frames - I'm working with INLA objects and am getting results from there that are used for further processing to get area specific (this are spatial models) values for regions (marginals, probabilities) that I use for maps & graphs, as well summary measurees I use to build a table for LaTeX that summarizes several models.

Comment: @radek Updated the answer, got help from @ Franck in chat room

Comment: Many thanks! Although not recommended (assign & get...), this solution gets me so far closest to what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: @radek may I ask how you get the variables in reality ? maybe building a list from them before working with them could be a proper way to go (an initial loop to build a list/dataframe you can populate to work on after without using assign/get)

Comment: Names are arbitrarily chosen by me.. indicating what the variable means and what was done to derive it, with main goal of being easily understandable later on. For instance, exponentiated `iid_unadj$marginals.random$HSA` becomes `zeta_model_1` or so.

Comment: @radek If I understand this properly, a dataframe with meaningful names for columns and meaningful names for rows could be a correct representation instead of the separated vars. But maybe we're stepping away from this question, I'll try to get some time to update the answer with a example of what I mean using this question data (model, and model_sum) (Side note, I'm not a statistician, so most use cases are unknown to me)